# Nested routing in angular 7, using modules and lazy loading

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I am having trouble creating angular routes. I have implemented feature modules and I am using routing for each of those modules. I want the routes to go from app to layout to dashboard and then to accounts. The route is not created properly, it seems dashboard is being skipped and route goes directly to accounts. Here is what it looks like when i use augury to debug the routes.

[image]

Here is my code for each route. each route is in a module of its own. I would really like to keep the routes separated in modules. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```js
//app routes

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: "",
    canActivate: [AuthGaurdService],
    loadChildren: "./layouts/layouts.module#LayoutsModule"
  },
  { path: "**", component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

//layout routes


const LayoutRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: LayoutsComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGaurdService],
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        canActivateChild: [AuthGaurdService],
        children: [
          {
            path: "account-information",
            loadChildren: "../account-information/account-information.module#AccountInformationModule"
          },
          {
            path: "",
            loadChildren: "../dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule"
          },
        ]
      }
      
    ]
  }
];

//dashboard routes


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGaurdService],
    children: [{
      path: "",
      canActivateChild: [AuthGaurdService],
      children: [
        {
          path: "accounts",
          loadChildren: "./accounts/accounts.module#AccountsModule"
        },
        {
          path: "",
          component: HomeComponent
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
];


//account routes

const AccountsRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "accounts",
    component: AccountsComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGaurdService],
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        canActivateChild: [AuthGaurdService],
        children: [
          { path: "transactions", component: TransactionsComponent },
          { path: "summary", component: SummaryComponent },
          { path: "earnings", component: EarningsComponent }
        ]
      }

    ]
  }
];
```

```html
<!--app.html -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<!-- layout.html -->
<div class="page-container">
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  <div class="page-content-wrapper ">
    <div class="content">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid container-fixed-lg footer">
      <app-footer></app-footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- dashboard.html -->
<div class="page-container">
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  <div class="page-content-wrapper ">
    <div class="content">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid container-fixed-lg footer">
      <app-footer></app-footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- accounts -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

this is what my page looks like when i to home 
[image]

this is the for accounts/summary
[image]

and my side menu looks like this 
`let retail: Array<Menu> = [
  {
    name: "Home",
    router_link: "",
    submenu: [],
    toggle_submenu: false,
    icon: ""
  },
  {
    name: "Accounts",
    router_link: "accounts/summary",
    toggle_submenu: false,
    icon: "",
    submenu: [
      {
        name: "Summary",
        router_link: "accounts/summary",
        toggle_submenu: false,
        icon: "",
        submenu: []
      },
      {
        name: "Tansactions",
        router_link: "accounts/transactions",
        toggle_submenu: false,
        icon: "",
        submenu: []
      },
      {
        name: "Earnings",
        router_link: "accounts/earnings",
        toggle_submenu: false,
        icon: "",
        submenu: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Sales",
    router_link: "sales",
    toggle_submenu: false,
    icon: "",
    submenu: []
  },
  {
    name: "Inventory",
    router_link: "inventory",
    toggle_submenu: false,
    icon: "",
    submenu: []
  },
  {
    name: "Upload",
    router_link: "upload",
    toggle_submenu: false,
    icon: "",
    submenu: []
  }
];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello friends i figured out the issue. I removed the import of accounts module in dashboard module. This made sure that when routes where generated accounts route was placed after dashboard. This is because I am lazy loading the modules. This is what my routes looked like after 
[This is what my routes looked like after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8igg.png)

Also make sure to add / in the child routes, so angular appends this route to its parent, ie accounts summary routerlink looks like this in my sidebar '/accounts/summary'.

Every thing else stayed the same. Now my accounts summary component was placed inside of my dashboard router link and i displayed next to my sidebar

Answer (score 1):

As I havn't seen your complete code, my guess is that your not able to properly navigate to your routes.

When you use lazy loaded modules, you don't need to provide the the prefix in child routes. For example In your `AppModule`:

```
{
    path: '', component: HomeComponent
    },
   {path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' 
  }
```

And in your `DashboardModule`

```
{
    path: '', component: DashboardComponent,
  },{
    path: 'accounts',
    loadChildren: '../accounts/accounts.module#AccountsModule' 
  }
```

Then in order to go to a route in your **dashboard.component.html**
You will write

```
<a [routerLink]="['accounts']"> Account</a>
```

Instead of

```
<a [routerLink]="['/dashboard', 'accounts']"> Account</a>
```

because in child lazy loaded modules the root path starts from the parent module which loaded it.

I have created a **stackblitz** [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pqi2fu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdashboard%2Fdashboard.module.ts) with a similar scenario.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello Asim thanks for responding, I have added screens and a json of my side menu

Comment: I am not using /dashboard to route to my dashboard page, i actually use accounts/routehere

Comment: Did you check the demo

Comment: I did, it is not exactly the way my project is setup, the demo has just one router-outlet but i need a router outlet in layouts and also in dashboard so i can have sidebar and navbar and route contents on the sidebar in there.

Comment: It would be great of you provide a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular) of your scenario or you can edit my demo

Comment: I am not very familiar with stackblitz I cant seem to create routing modules in there, the scenario i want is - in my app page i can route to either login, pagenotfound or layouts,- in layouts I want to have a navbar and then place all other pages below the navbar, so layouts will have a router outlet where when a link is clicked in the navbar  it gets places in that router outlet. one of the routes will be dashboard, and in dashboard I will have a sidebar and a router outlet and in the router outlet i will place the routes from the side bar